# Develop applications for ipod

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch

I want to develop an application for ipod . I don t have ipod device for test . I have just an iphone 4. It is posible to have in xcode simulator ipod? How should I test it .

Comment: It is not possible to deploy an app for the ipod touch but not for the iPhone.... So really you might not want to test on the iphone

Comment: first of all xcode doesn't have emulator it has simulator. secondly did you try atleast once to run your application on your iPhone4?

Comment: There is no separate programming platform for iphone. You can use your iphone for testing..

Comment: An iPod is an iPhone without phone, if it works on iphone and it doesn't use phone capabilities, it will work on the ipod

Comment: ipod is just an iphone without some hardware, just avoid to use methods and classes that use iPhone specific hardware (as gps, or camera-not in old ipod models) and you can use the simulator or your iPhone to test

Comment: Basically your iPhone app will be work in iPod touch devices. So just develop an app and test in our iPhone device. It will work. There is call function is only thing u can't test in iPod (iPod not supports call and messaging).

Comment: @Yuvaraj.M in iOS 5 the iPod Touch will support messaging via iMessage you can even use `MFMEssageComposeViewController`

Comment: i don t use calls and message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iPod touch is internally the exact same as an iPhone, just without the phone-specific hardware.

You can use your iPhone 4 or the Simulator to develop apps.

If you use iPhone-specific features, be sure to test to see if they are available on the designated hardware.